# Swift/Spritekit- How do I page through an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I'm a total newbie, so here goes...I need help figuring out how to page through an array of sprites in a SpriteKit game. How would I change this code to only show 4 items at a time and write a function that would "move to next page"?

```
let myArray:Array<String> = [sprite1, sprite2, sprite3, sprite4, sprite5, sprite6, sprite7, sprite8, sprite9, sprite10, sprite11, sprite12]

for (index, item) in myArray.enumerate() {
    let gofoodsprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"\(item)")
    gofoodsprite.name = item
    gofoodsprite.position = CGPointMake(gobuttonX, 275)
    gobuttonX = gobuttonX + 105
    self.addChild(gofoodsprite)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a variable to manage the page number, and then change your loop accordingly:

```
var pageNumber = 0

let myArray:Array<String> = [sprite1, sprite2, sprite3, sprite4, sprite5, sprite6, sprite7, sprite8, sprite9, sprite10, sprite11, sprite12]

for var i in 0..<4 {
    let item = myArray[pageNumber*4 + i]
    let gofoodsprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"\(item)")
    gofoodsprite.name = item
    gofoodsprite.position = CGPointMake(gobuttonX, 275)
    gobuttonX = gobuttonX + 105
    self.addChild(gofoodsprite)
}
```

Then your "next page" code adds 1 to `pageNumber` and calls the loop again.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I needed!